# Python class inheritance and super() behavior?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super

I'm attempting to teach myself about super() and class inheritance in python unsuccessfully. Given the following code, can someone tell me why what I  expect to happen...isn't?

```
import random
enemy_list = []

class Entity(object):

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 1
        self.attack_power = .05

class Enemy(Entity):

    def __init__(self, name, target):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(name)
        self.lvl = random.randint(target.lvl - 2, target.lvl + 2)
        self.health *= self.lvl * target.health
        self.attack_power *= self.lvl

def createEnemy(enemy):
    enemy_list.append(Enemy(enemy, player))
    return enemy_list

enemy_amount = random.randint(1, 5)
while enemy_amount > 0:
    createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))
    enemy_amount -= 1

for i in enemy_list:
    print "(", i.lvl, i.name, i.attack_power, i.health, ")"
```

Why is this code outputting:

```
( 2 <__main__.Enemy object at 0x7faa040b3050> 0.1 80 )
( 5 <__main__.Enemy object at 0x7faa040b30d0> 0.25 200 )
( 3 <__main__.Enemy object at 0x7faa040b3150> 0.15 120 )
( 5 <__main__.Enemy object at 0x7faa040b31d0> 0.25 200 )
```

Instead of the expected:

```
( 2 goblin 0.1 80 )
( 5 goblin 0.25 200 )
( 3 goblin 0.15 120 )
( 5 goblin 0.25 200 )
```

Comment: what is `player`, assuming it is an instance of `Enemy`?

Comment: @edhurtig player is another instance of Entity, pretty similar code to whats shown in the Enemy class but with different math (no target to base data off of)

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense, because I've little idea about what I speak of...
I'm only using it here to determing the lvl of the enemy and make adjustments to it's attributes depending on that lvl.

Comment: Makes sense, seems like @Markus got it

Answer (score 1):

The `enemy` being passed in on this line:

```
enemy_list.append(Enemy(enemy, player))
```

Perhaps you want something like:

```
def createEnemy(enemy_name):
    enemy_list.append(Enemy(enemy_name, player))
    return enemy_list

while enemy_amount > 0:
    createEnemy("goblin", player)
    enemy_amount -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Due to your comment, and the comments of others, I was able to figure out I didn't want <code>createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))</code> I wanted <code>createEnemy("goblin")</code>. I can't say I understand it any better, but the "flow" of it is starting to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in a string for `name`, but an enemy object. The order of execution is:

```
createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))
```

then

```
enemy_list.append(Enemy(enemy, player))
```

then

```
super(Enemy, self).__init__(name)
```

At this point `name` is not a string but an enemy object.

Comment: Thank you very much. Due to your comment, and the comments of others, I was able to figure out I didn't want <code>createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))</code> I wanted <code>createEnemy("goblin")</code>. I can't say I understand it any better, but the "flow" of it is starting to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an `Enemy` object in for the name

```
def createEnemy(enemy):
    enemy_list.append(Enemy(enemy, player))
    return enemy_list


createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))
```

You call `createEnemy`, passing in an `Enemy`.  Inside `createEnemy`, you pass that enemy object as the first argument to create another `Enemy` (the first argument should be a name).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was the one that gave me my moment of clarity, even though it says very similar to the others. 

Due to your comment I was able to figure out I didn't want <code>createEnemy(Enemy("goblin", player))</code> I wanted <code>createEnemy("goblin")</code>. I can't say I understand it any better, but the "flow" of it is starting to make more sense.